# Dask: Create dayOfWeek column from date string

Tags: python, dask

I have a dask dataframe, `dfs`, with a date column, `IR_START_DATE`. I'd like to create a new `dayofweek` column using said date column.

I can achieve this using the following code:

```
  ddf.to_datetime(dfs['IR_START_DATE']).dt.dayofweek.compute()
```

However, I'm having trouble storing this to it's own column. 
E.g., I've tried:

- Assigning as column:

  ```
  dfs['yeah'] = ddf.to_datetime(dfs['IR_START_DATE']).dt.dayofweek.compute()
  ```
- Using `map_partition()`:

  ```
  def compute_dow(df):
      date_time = ddf.to_datetime(df['IR_START_DATE']).dt
      dow = date_time.dayofweek
      return dow

  dow = dfs.map_partitions(compute_dow)
  ```
- Using `map()`:

  ```
  dfs['IR_START_DATE'].map(lambda x: ddf.to_datetime(x['IR_START_DATE']).dt.dayofweek, meta = ('time', 'datetime64[ns]')).compute()
  ```

Obviously I'm missing some fundamental piece of `dask` knowledge here, please point me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first two methods were very close!

This should work:

```
dfs['yeah'] = ddf.to_datetime(dfs['IR_START_DATE']).dt.dayofweek
```

Note the lack of `compute()` - you do not want to make a pandas dataframe, you want the column to refer back to the original data in the normal dask lazy way.

For `map_partitions`, you could have done

```
def compute_dow(df):
    date_time = ddf.to_datetime(df['IR_START_DATE']).dt
    df['dow'] = date_time.dayofweek
    return df
```

Note that we are passing in a dataframe and getting back a dataframe. Also, it would help when calling `map_partitions` to provide the `meta=` argument, to reduce the inference dask needs to make (read the method docs).